Deghotify: “Tghght gghth Gghggh tght Ggh ghgh gghggh tgh.”
Deghotify: “Tghght gghth Gghggh tght Ggh ghgh gghggh tgh.”
All pronunciations have been taken from the CMU Pronouncing Dictionary. All words of the sentence that aren’t proper nouns exist in the Scrabble TWL dictionary.

Will accept this one? "Tonight is the night to fight"

@Moti No, from what word do you take the spelling for /n/?

If the words aren't proper nouns, why do two of them, in the middle of a sentence, have captial 'G'. Is this something that will become clear later?

@hexomino I didn’t say no words were proper nouns. With the variety of sounds kind of limited by only using the three letters, proper nouns are necessary for the sentence to be grammatical.

@RomanOdaisky My apologies, I've misread

@RomanOdaisky How grammatical is the sentence? For example, does every noun have all its necessary determiners and verb agreement, or does it just need to read like a newspaper headline? (e.g. "New bill Congress passed vetoed" vs. "The new bill that Congress passed was vetoed")

@Rin'sFouriertransform I aimed to make it fully grammatical, hopefully I succeeded

This is essentially "guess what I'm thinking".

@RosieF I tried to make sure as few as possible sentences are grammatical and make some semblance of sense, the intended solution is perhaps not unique but shouldn’t be far from that.

Posting this as a separate answer since it's in a completely different vein compared to the first.
The sentence is

 Soaked coach Jojo showed Joe foe cocoa dough.

interpreted as

 [[Soaked coach] Jojo] [showed [Joe] [foe [cocoa dough]]].
 Jojo, a soaked coach, showed Joe cocoa dough from a foe.

and spellings from

 T.gh.gh.t -- soaked: <t> as /s/ from Aerospatiale, <gh> as /ow/ from Edinburgh, <gh> as /k/ from laugher, <t> as /t/
 g.gh.th -- coach: <g> as /k/ from DeRegt, <gh> as /ow/, <th> as /ch/ from posthumous
 G.gh.g.gh -- Jojo: <g> as /jh/, <gh> as /ow/
 t.gh.t -- showed: <t> as /sh/ from actual, <gh> as /ow/, <t> as /d/ from Taoism
 G.gh -- Joe: <g> as /jh/, <gh> as /ow/
 gh.gh -- foe: <gh> as /f/ from rough, <gh> as /ow/
 g.gh.g.gh -- cocoa: <g> as /k/ from laugher, <gh> as /ow/
 t.gh -- dough: <t> as /d/, <gh> as /ow/

Solution path
Here's the list of relevant pronunciations by letter/digraph from the CMU pronunciation dictionary:

 t: /t/, /d/ (Taoist), /ch/ (Tewes), /s/ (Aerospatiale), /sh/ (actual)
 th: /th/, /dh/, /t/ (Thai), /ch/ (posthumous)
 g: /jh/, /g/, /zh/ (homage), /k/ (DeRegt), /hh/ (Geraldo)
 gh: /g/, /hh/ (O’Donoghue), /f/ (cough), /k/ (laugher), /p/ (hiccoughs), /th/ (Keighly), /ow/ (Edinburgh)


 This basically means that at least one of the <gh>s in every word has to be the vowel /ow/.

This gives the following possible words for the sentence:

 T.gh.gh.t: Choked, Chokes, Doped, Dopes, Soaked, Soaks
 g.gh.th: goat, coat, coach
 G.gh.g.gh: Jojo
 t.gh.t: dote, toad, towed, showed
 G.gh: Joe/Jo
 gh.gh: go, hoe, foe, oaf, oak, oath
 g.gh.g.gh: go-go, cocoa
 t.gh: dough, tow, toe, sow, sew, show

For the first word, I'll arbitrarily go with

 "soaked", although any of the past participles will work.

That still leaves a few ambiguous words:
tght is likely

 "showed" -- it's the only one that can take an indirect and direct object, necessary to tie all the nouns together especially since none of the verbs that ghgh could be are conjugated for the singular third person

and tgh should be

 "dough" -- it's the only uncountable noun. "toe" and "show" need a determiner to be completely grammatical, and none of the verbs really work here

This leaves ghgh, which can be the widest variety of things.

 I'm going to go with "foe". "foe" and "oak" are the only adjectives, and "foe" makes more sense than "oak" here.


I agree that “nation” doesn’t imply 〈t〉=/SH/, can you find a word that does imply exactly that? And my sentence, which is also silly but which I think is slightly more in line with English norms, includes other sounds for 〈g〉 and 〈th〉 that this answer so far misses.

alright, looks like I needed to look at both the pronunciation and the original word because I apparently mispronounce a bunch of stuff -- I always thought "actual" had a /ch/ for <t>, but CMU has /sh/...

I have to comment that pronouncing the 'gh' in Edinburgh as 'o' sounds awful (I guess it may be an American thing?). Really it's more like a short 'a' like at the end of the word 'comma'.

@hexomino The best thing about using a specific dictionary is that such comments can be redirected at the authors of the dictionary. Related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35rqRFXPWJo

@RomanOdaisky Edited two words based on the updated pronunciations, although most of the sentence is still the same structure.

This kind of disproves Rosie’s comment, because your answer is almost exactly my intended solution, which was “qbcrq pbnpu Pbpb fubjrq Wbr snhk pbpbn qbhtu”.

ahhh, forgot about that homophone. This was quite fun and unearthed some interesting spellings/transcription choices, although the bulk of the work was pretty much brute forcing the CMU by hand

Partial Answer
Not sure if this is going in the right direction. Will use ARPABET for phonemes (/uw/) and IPA for close phonetic descriptions ([uː]). I'll use <these> to refer to spelling, so <oo> might be pronounced /uw/, and someone speaking my dialect might say [ʉw].
My dialect also merges cot and caught to /aa/, so I'll refer to both phonemes in merged cases as /aa/.
I tried to find all the "normal" transcriptions of all combinations of [ght]+ spellings in the CMU by doing filtering of common pronunciations:

 <t>: /t/ (tea), /d/ (Taoism), /ch/ (Tewes), silent (listen)
 <g>: /jh/ (image), /g/ (gif graphics), /zh/ (homage), silent (sign)
 <h>: /hh/ (house), /q/ -- glottal stop (uh-oh), silent (hour)
 <gh>: /g/ (ghee), /hh/ (O’Donoghue), /f/ (cough), /k/ (laugher), /p/ (hiccough), silent (sigh)
 <th>: /th/ (thatch), /dh/ (this), /t/ (Thai)
 <ght>: /ch/ (righteous), /t/ (night)
 <ghth>: /th/ (eighth)

Notice that among this list,

 there's not a single vowel phoneme. Thus, we have to get a little creative.

We can use the English phonological law that

 there are no contrastively long phonemes, neither vowels nor consonants -- everything ends up reducing (for vowels, only if it's unstressed, which is easy to posit). That is, /ihih/ surfaces as simply [ɪ] and /tt/ surfaces as just [t]. Of course, this isn't true for diphthongs -- /owow/ sounds like [oʊwoʊ] (think someone saying "oh! oh!"), but a diphthong followed by a vowel that matches the second part of the diphthong reduces into the diphthong. I'll find a less awful example somewhere, but attaching the adjective-forming morpheme "-y" [iː] (e.g. "shake" + "y" = "shaky") to a word like "sky" or "gray" forces you to overtly stress the "-y" morpheme to make it sound different from the base word -- you end up saying [ˈskaɪ.ˈʔiː] or [ˈskaɪ.ˈjiː], otherwise [ˈskaɪ.iː] just reduces to [skaɪ].
 While we're at it, we can also consider all the rules where stuff changes voicing in a bunch of contexts (e.g. /d/ becomes [t] in "mucked" but stays [d] in "mugged") to expand the list of phonemes. I won't go into the specific contexts here, but native speakers should just intuitively be able to tell when it makes sense for something to change.
 Applying these rules to ghotiness, in a word like <night>, <gh> is generally considered silent, but nothing is stopping it from being pronounced as part of the /ay/ or part of the /t/. We can plausibly get [naɪt] from any of these options for <gh>:
 <n>: /n/
 <i>: /ay/
 <gh>: /ih/, /iy/, /y/, /t/, /d/
 <t>: /t/

Of course, none of these are really options anyone sane would consider, even when compounds and morphological derivations aren't considered (nobody thinks <gh> is pronounced as part of /r/ in "highrise" or /er/ in "higher"). But it's the only way to get what we need. Combing the dictionary with these in mind, here are more options for the above phonemes:

 <t>: /k/ (tkacz), /z/ (tsar), /s/ (tsunami)
 <g>: /ih/, /iy/, /y/ (sign), /ah/, /ax/, /n/ (foreign), /aa/ (lasagna), /uh/, /uw/, /w/ (impugn), /eh/, /m/ (phlegm), /ae/ (diaphragm)
 <gh>: /ih/, /iy/, /y/ (high), /uh/, /uw/, /w/ (through), /aa/, /d/, /t/ (caught), /n/ (Vaughn)

 And, worst of all,
 <h>: /iy/, /ih/, /y/ (Yahweh), /uh/, /uw/, /w/ (Pooh), /ah/ (Sarah), /aa/, /n/ (John), /ae/, /m/ (Graham), /l/ (Dahl), /r/ (Rhine), /d/ (Gandhi), /t/ (Thai), /g/, /k/ (technology), /s/, /z/ (exhort), /w/, /eh/ (where)...
 And if we twist the pronunciation of the spelling of other letters just a little, we can force <h> to be /sh/ (show, church), /zh/ (Zhang), /th/ (thatch), /dh/ (this), and honestly, pretty much any non-diphthong vowel.

Ignoring the possibilities of the last phoneme and trying to deghotify the phrase,

 let's take a look at the first word. <tgh> doesn't exist in any word, and neither does <ghg>, so our best options for segmentation are <t>, <gh>, <gh>, <t>, or <t>, <gh>, <ght>. If we only allow the first <gh> to be a vowel, this gives us the following options:
 <t>: /d, ch, k, z, s/
 <gh>: /uw, uh, ow, aa, ih, iy/
 <ght>: /g, hh, f, k, p, n/ /t/, or /ch, t/

 Assuming <ght> as one phoneme:
 - cute?, suit
 - soot
 - coach, dote, coat
 - dot, taught, caught, sought
 - ditch, chit, kit, zit, sit
 - cheat, seat

 <ght> as two phonemes:
 - duked, duped, cooped, souped
 - cooked
 - doped, don’t, choked, coked, coped, soaked, soaped
 - doffed, docked, chopped, coughed, caulked, copped, Kant, soft, socked, sopped
 - chipped, kicked, zipped, sift
 - cheeked, seeped

 On the other hand, if the second <gh> is a vowel, we have
 <t>: /d, ch, k, z, s/
 <gh>: /g, hh, f, k, p, n/
 <gh>: /uw, uh, ow, aa, ih, iy/
 <t>: /ch, t/
 and since the only possible initial consonant clusters among these are /sk/, /sp/, and /sn/, this gives us
 - scooch, scoot, snoot
 - scotch, Scot, spot, snot
 - skit, spit, snitch
 - skeet, speech

This is already making several assumptions with several heuristics, and completely ignoring <h> as its own phoneme, as well as any of them possibly being silent. If I get time, maybe I'll use NLTK to sort through all the options to figure out something syntactic for the whole sentence.
Or maybe OP will rule out some of the more crazy categories of transcriptions and narrow the field a bit. :)

There’s a much more straightforward way of getting a vowel sound that’s very much in a ghotiy spirit.

To be more specific, each of the donor words has a single letter or letter cluster that corresponds to an unusual sound. Everything around that has a normal sound-to-spelling correspondence, no silent letters, e. g. I’m not saying that 〈a〉=/æ/, 〈x〉=/k/, 〈e〉=/s/.

ahh, completely mispronounced a certain Scottish city when I was going through the list.
